# C# Action center toast notification action Back to Desktop app

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-10, toast

C# Action center toast notification action Back to Desktop app.

I do not have an app to publish to app store. But my app is a desktop app. I can send toast notifications from this desktop app easily without any issue and using toast notification actions I can handle callbacks too. Now the issue I am facing callback to those actions works only when my app is in running mode. If I close my DESKTOP application those actions does not do anything. I also checked Background and protocol type of activationType on the actions. However, these activationType work only with Universal window application type project, whereas my application is a C# console / desktop application.

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36403406/3836163 :

> Win32 apps need to set up a COM server in order to have toasts persisted in Action Center: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/10/15/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10.aspx

This blog post indicates that a COM server is needed to have toasts persisted in the Action Center and to handle toast activation when the app is not running
butI was not able to make the last toast activation work when the app is not running

There is a small documentation on MSDN : [Respond to toast activations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt643715(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts

even this sample app has similar behavior. Non persistent toast with Action center and Times out.