# Toast Notifications does not appear in Action Center after time out

Tags: c#, windows-10, toast

Toast notification in Windows 10 is behaving strange. It does not stay in the action center even if user has not taken any actions yet. This behavior is with custom notification and generic both. Toast notification is generated using a Windows desktop application not using a universal window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779767/unexpected-behavior-of-toast-notifications-for-windows-10-desktop-applications

I also found similar issue, but no answer to that post too.

Comment: Any suggestion from anyone?

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772192/toastnotifications-sent-from-powershell-disappear-from-action-center/39564998#39564998

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072291/3836163) :

> Win32 apps need to set up a COM server in order to have toasts persisted in Action Center: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/10/15/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10.aspx

You can go on https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts to view some working samples in C++ and C#.

Comment: it not c++ app but c# app, do I still need a COM registration? I looked at the C# sample of https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts. They do not have any COM registration logic. However, when I am using the sample app there also I have both the issues mentioned above.

Comment: @rocky there is COM registration logic in https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/blob/master/CS/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L92.  For the issues, you are right, toasts do no stay in the action center because the sample create Win8 style toast, that do not have logic for action center. You will have to update it to use Windows 10 toasts. I forgot that I had already did that so mine was working. You can look at https://gist.github.com/k94ll13nn3/f3dce111e525a02c2bc9 to see how you can use Windows 10 toast. I will try to upload a working W10 sample when I have time.

Comment: Its using Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd. Which I was trying to avoid and thought using Windows.winmd is better.

Comment: @rocky I'm not sure, I got it to work only by adding the TargetPlatformVersion and adding reference to Windows.UI and Windows.Data

Comment: Where did you find Windows.UI and Windows.Data references?

Comment: They should be in the "Windows" tab, in the "Add reference" menu, but sometimes they do not appear, so you may have to manually add them to your .csproj